# I/O warning while running emulator on Android 1.2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to android app development and trying to run my first Hello World app.

This demo is running fine on USB device but its not running on emulator.

**Emulator is running fine with the below warning at AVD console:**

```
E:\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_22
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:/C:/Users/D/.AndroidStudio1.2/config/options/updates.xml"
adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:/C:/Users/D/.AndroidStudio1.2/config/options/updates.xml"
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
 - Start Android Studio
 - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
 - Click "SDK Tools" tab
 - Check "Android SDK Tools" checkbox
 - Click "OK"
```

I am not sure if this I/O warning is causing emulator not running my demo app on it.

FYI, emulator is not in locked state, still its not installing app and showing hello word.

I also did not find **updates.xml** file mentioned in the warning.

for Emulator, I am using **Nexus_4_api_22**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you are using API 22 you're not using android 1.2.2, you're using 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Warning message told you the answer :

```
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
```

BTW, there is no Android 1.2.2, the oldest release version of Android is 1.5 .